# Как ограничить поворот по y в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Уже пару часов мучаюсь с этим пытался при помощи Mathf.Clamp, но поворот не ограничивался + к этому появлялась всякого рода наркомания. Помогите пожалуйста, вот код:

```
FixedUpdate()
 {
  float yRotGo = rotateY();
  Vector3 yrot = new Vector3(0f, Mathf.Clamp(-yRotGo, -60, 60), 0f) * sensetive;
 }

private static float rotateX()
 {
  return Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
 }

private static float rotateY()
 {
  return Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
 }
```

Comment: В юнити поровот хранится в кватернионах, а здесь Vector3. Можете дополнить свой вопрос, где используется `yrot`? Потому что по этому фрагменту я смотрю что все правильно. Навскидку могу только посоветовать поместить `Clamp` внутрь функции `rotateY()`, раз уж содали такую обертку.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(transform.rotation.y > 60f)
{
 Vector3 yrot = new Vector3(0f, 60f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: теперь только влево-вправо поворачивает)

Comment: Ну так сделайте так, как Вам надо. Пример кода я написал, дальше разберите его и сделайте как надо. Ничего сложного нет.

Comment: @Dodik, если бы автор мог сделать так, как ему надо, наверное, данного вопроса здесь не было бы?